# XML parsing by field name with Java

Tags: java, xml-parsing

I want to parse an XML file but I couldn't get the values of each field. Can somebody help?

I can get the names of each field but couldn't find a way to get the values of each field.

My Xml file is structured like this.

```
    <record>
      <field name="Name" key="DEU">Germany</field>
      <field name="Country">Germany</field>
      <field name="Year">1960</field>
      <field name="Value">72814900</field>
      <field name="Category">Europe</field>
    </record>
    <record>
      <field name="Name" key="DEU">Germany</field>
      <field name="Country">Germany</field>
      <field name="Year">1961</field>
      <field name="Value">73377632</field>
      <field name="Category">Europe</field>
    </record>
```

My parsing code:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document document = documentBuilder.parse(file);

        NodeList list = (NodeList) document.getElementsByTagName("field");

        Map<String, String> data = new HashMap<>();

        for(int i = 0; i < list.getLength(); i++) {
            Element element = (Element)list.item(i);
            String nameAttribute = element.getAttribute("name");
            //String firstname = element.getElementsByTagName("firstname").item(0).getTextContent();
            String firstname = element.get;




            data.put(nameAttribute, "value"); <-- my problem is the "value" part


        }

        for(Map.Entry field : data.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println(field.getKey() + ": " + field.getValue());
        }
```

Comment: FYI: [There are 134,000 Stackoverflow search results on this topic](https://www.google.com/search?q=parse+xml+java+site:stackoverflow.com&client=safari&rls=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjxwf-r94HxAhWTZs0KHbVjCpAQrQIoBHoECB8QBQ)

Comment: Your code doesn't compile, but `Element` extends `Node`, and `Node` has a method to retrieve its text content. Use it.